# leetcode 39. Combination Sum why do I have to return after I get one solution?

Tags: python, depth-first-search, backtracking

so the question is like this:

Given an array of **distinct** integers `candidates` and a target integer `target`, return *a list of all **unique combinations** of `candidates` where the chosen numbers sum to* `target`. You may return the combinations in **any order**.

The **same** number may be chosen from `candidates` an **unlimited number of times**. Two combinations are unique if the frequency of at least one of the chosen numbers is different.

The test cases are generated such that the number of unique combinations that sum up to `target` is less than `150` combinations for the given input.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: candidates = [2,3,6,7], target = 7
Output: [[2,2,3],[7]]
Explanation:
2 and 3 are candidates, and 2 + 2 + 3 = 7. Note that 2 can be used multiple times.
7 is a candidate, and 7 = 7.
These are the only two combinations.
```

I use backtrack ingto solve this , here is my code

```
class Solution:
    def combinationSum(self, candidates: List[int], target: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        
        res = []
        
        def backtrack(i,cur,total):
            if total == target:
                res.append(cur[:])
            
            if i>=len(candidates) or total > target:
               return
          
            cur.append(candidates[i])
            backtrack(i, cur,total+candidates[i])
            cur.pop()
            
            backtrack(i+1,cur, total)
        
        backtrack(0,[],0)
        return res
```

At first I didn't put `return`  after `res.append(cur[:])`  so i got the woring result `[[2,2,3],[2,2,3],[2,2,3],[2,2,3],[7],[7]] instead of  [[2,2,3],[7]]` .So I add `return`   to fix it, but honestly I have no idea how this works, isn't it gonna automatically hit the constrain since total already equals target? How did I get dupulicate returns?

Also I was thinking if I sort the array, for example if I get [2,6] it's already bigger that 7 so I don't have to iterate [2,7], or if I get [2,2,2,3], so I don't have to go through [2,2,2,6],[2,2,,2,7] etc. I get the idea but I don't know how to put it into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print each your steps and you will see why it works.

For example, if you don't add `return` after `res.append(cur[:])`, what happens?

```
i =  1  cur =  [2, 2, 3] total =  7
```

Then you will add `cur` to `res`

```
res =  [[2, 2, 3]]
```

But you will go next because `i = 1 < len(candidates)` AND `total < target`.

```
i =  2  cur =  [2, 2, 3] total =  7
```

It will add one more to `res`.

```
res =  [[2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3]]
```

So, you can change your code in one of following ways.

1. Add `return` after add `cur` to `res` as your idea.
2. change condition of second `if` to `total >= target`.

Comment: Thank you GAVD, I used a debugger provided by leetcode, and I see what's going on. Other than that is there other ways to print each steps out? Sorry I am quite a noob.